# Tightly covering a shape with grid (rasterization)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, asymptote

I am trying to re-create the images below.

I found them here: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~erin/docs/dimension.pdf which is a document written by Erin Pearse. It follows a lot of Falconer's Fractal Geometry book (which is what I am reading).

Would someone be able to help my automatically place the grids over the set please?

The shape I am using is produced by:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true,scale=0.3]
    \draw [fill=blue!20, name path global=F,rotate=30] 
      (-3.5, 0.5) .. (-3.0, 2.5) .. (-1.0, 3.5) .. (1.5, 3.0) .. 
      ( 4.0, 3.5) .. ( 5.0, 2.5) .. ( 5.0, 0.5) .. (2.5,-1.0) .. 
      ( 0.0,-1.2).. (-3.0,-2.0) .. (-3.5, 0.5);
    \node at (-2,1) {$F$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: It would be useful if you showed us how you draw the `F` domain in the first place. You also state you want help covering **automatically**. Maybe you can show us how you'd do this manually ?

Comment: This would take about an hour on Inkscape or any mouse-capable software for graphics instead of implementing a full script for each of these.

Comment: @percusse And to add to the challenge, these 7 pictures show various covering methods, with at least 5 different algorithm !

Comment: @marsupilam what can I say? I like to challenge you guys.

Comment: @JSharpee Maybe it would be better if you restrict your question to one of the shapes and keep the other shapes to challenge yourself.

Comment: Sure thing, but you may have noticed that the *do-everything-for-me* is not the most popular type of (tikz) questions, around here ?!

Comment: @samcarter ok good point. If I had one of the grid ones I'm sure I could do the other grid from that.

Comment: @marsupilam I am not asking for anyone to do-everything-for-me. I would just like an idea as to where to start since I have not done anything of this sort before.

Comment: @JSharpee I think this could be a **very good question**, with almost assured very skilled answer, if you provided the tikz drawing of the filled shape, and stated explicitely you would be content with the grid covering, with an appropriate illustration (just the 3 relevant pics). *And I am less confident than you in the possibility for the other covering methods*

Comment: Please can you complete your code so we can compile it? A full example is much more useful than a code fragment. Also, right now, I don't understand the question.  How is this done manually? Or what would it look like to do it automatically? No idea.

Comment: FRANKLY SPEAKING, isn't implementing rasterization in a vector graphic language the opposite way to go...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit of a fiddle, and it takes *ages*, but...

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,hobby}
\begin{document}
\foreach \d [count=\i] in {1cm, 0.5cm, 0.25cm,0.125cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[use Hobby shortcut, closed=true, scale=0.3, local bounding box=F]
    \draw [fill=gray, name path global=F] 
      (-3.5, 0.5) .. (-3.0, 2.5) .. (-1.0, 3.5) .. (1.5, 3.0) .. 
      ( 4.0, 3.5) .. ( 5.0, 2.5) .. ( 5.0, 0.5) .. (2.5,-1.0) .. 
      ( 0.0,-1.2).. (-3.0,-2.0) .. (-3.5, 0.5);
    \node at (-2,2) {$F$};
\end{scope}
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{F}{south west}}{\pgfpointanchor{F}{north east}}
\pgfgetlastxy\w\h
\pgfmathsetmacro\W{int(ceil(\w/\d))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H{int(ceil(\h/\d))}
\begin{scope}[shift=(F.south west)]
\begin{scope}
\clip \pgfextra{\expandafter\pgfsetpath\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@F\endcsname};
\foreach \x in {0,...,\W}
  \foreach \y in {0,...,\H}        
    \draw (\x*\d-\d/2,\y*\d-\d/2) rectangle ++(\d,\d);
\end{scope}
\foreach \x in {0,...,\W}{
  \foreach \y in {0,...,\H}{
    \path [name path global=S] (\x*\d-\d/2,\y*\d-\d/2) rectangle ++(\d,\d);
    \draw [name intersections={of=F and S, total=\T}]
      \ifnum\T>0 (\x*\d-\d/2,\y*\d-\d/2) rectangle ++(\d,\d)\fi;
  }
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although it might not be expected to work with holes, by adding `(1,0.75) circle [radius=1.5]` at the end of the "hobby" path, the `0.125cm` iteration looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Congratulations. This method works even if F contains holes!

Answer (score 4):

Obviously heavily inspired by Mark Wibrow's answer.

The algorithm is saner, though, since it scales linearly, instead of quadratically.

Now with holes, like the cool kids `;)` *(thanks to Paul Gaborit for the remark !)*

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,hobby}
\begin{document}
\foreach \d [count=\i] in {1cm, 0.5cm, 0.25cm, 0.125cm}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[use Hobby shortcut, closed=true, scale=0.3, local bounding box=F]
  \draw [fill=blue!20, name path global=F,rotate=30] 
    (-3.5, 0.5) .. (-3.0, 2.5) .. (-1.0, 3.5) .. (1.5, 3.0) .. 
    ( 4.0, 3.5) .. ( 5.0, 2.5) .. ( 5.0, 0.5) .. (2.5,-1.0) .. 
    ( 0.0,-1.2).. (-3.0,-2.0) .. (-3.5, 0.5)
    (-1,1) circle (1.7cm) 
    {
      [rounded corners=1mm,rotate=50]
      (-3.1,1.9) rectangle (-.2,.6)
    };
\end{scope}
\path(F.south west);
\pgfgetlastxy\w\h
\pgfmathsetmacro\Wmin{int(floor(\w/\d))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Hmin{int(floor(\h/\d))}
\path(F.north east);
\pgfgetlastxy\w\h
\pgfmathsetmacro\Wmax{int(ceil(\w/\d))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Hmax{int(ceil(\h/\d))}

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\opa}{min(100,300*\d/1cm)}
  \tikzset{myGrid/.style={red!\opa}}
\begin{scope} % inner tiling
  \clip \pgfextra{\expandafter\pgfsetpath\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@F\endcsname};
  \draw[myGrid] (\Wmin*\d, \Hmin*\d) grid[step=\d] (\Wmax*\d, \Hmax*\d);
\end{scope}

\foreach \x in {\Wmin,...,\Wmax} % first pass, with vertical lines
{
  \path [name path global=S] (\x*\d,\Hmin*\d) -- (\x*\d,\Hmax*\d);
  \path [name intersections={of=F and S, name=i, total=\T}] node {\xdef\CC{\T}};
    \ifnum\CC>0 \foreach \s in {1,...,\CC}
    {
      \path (i-\s); \pgfgetlastxy\w\h
      \pgfmathsetmacro\hh{int(floor(\h/\d))}
      \draw[myGrid] (\w-\d,\hh*\d) grid[step=\d] (\w+\d,\hh*\d+\d);
    }
    \fi;
}
\foreach \y in {\Hmin,...,\Hmax} % second pass, with horizontal lines
{
  \path [name path global=S] (\Wmin*\d,\y*\d) -- (\Wmax*\d,\y*\d);
  \path [name intersections={of=F and S, name=i, total=\T}] node {\xdef\CC{\T}};
    \ifnum\CC>0 \foreach \s in {1,...,\CC}
    {
      \path (i-\s); \pgfgetlastxy\w\h
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ww{int(floor(\w/\d))}
      \draw[myGrid] (\ww*\d,\h-\d) grid[step=\d] (\ww*\d+\d,\h+\d);
    }
    \fi;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Congratulations. This method works even if F contains holes!

Comment: @PaulGaborit Merci ! Don't Mark Wibrow's method and this one work under exactly the same conditions, though ?

Comment: You are right... but linear time with holes is better than quadratic time with holes! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Mandatory `Asymptote` `MWE`:

[image]

[image]

```
% boxcount.tex :
%
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
    size(5cm);
    guide[] g;
    g.push((-3.5,0.5)..(-3,2.5)..(-1,3.5)..(1.5,3)..(4,3.5)..(5,2.5)
    ..(5,0.5)..(2.5,-1)..(0,-1.25)..(-3,-2)..cycle);
    pair gmin=min(g[0]), gmax=max(g[0]);
    g.push(shift(2.5,1.2)*rotate(18)*scale(0.4)*shift(-(gmin+gmax)/2)*reverse(g[0]));
    g.push(shift(-1,0)*rotate(-30)*scale(0.3)*shift(-(gmin+gmax)/2)*reverse(g[0]));
    for(int i=0;i<g.length;++i) g[i]=shift(-gmin)*g[i];

    void boxcount(guide[] g, int step){
        pair gmin=min(g[0]), gmax=max(g[0]);
        real gw=gmax.x-gmin.x;
        real gh=gmax.y-gmin.y;
        real u=min(gw,gh);
        int n,nx,ny;
        n=2^step;
        nx=ceil(gw*n/(u));
        ny=ceil(gh*n/(u));
        guide gb=box(-(u/n,u/n)/2,(u/n,u/n)/2);

        int[] count=array((nx+1)*(ny+1),0);
        pair v;

        filldraw(g,gray(0.8),black+0.4bp);

        for(int i=0;i<=ny;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<=nx;++j){
                v=(u*j/n, u*i/n);
                if( inside(g[0],v)){ 
                    count[i*(nx+1)+j      ]=1;
                    count[i*(nx+1)+j-1    ]=1;
                    count[(i-1)*(nx+1)+j-1]=1;
                    count[(i-1)*(nx+1)+j  ]=1;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int k=1;k<g.length;++k){
            for(int m=0;m<count.length;++m){
                if(count[m]>0){
                    int i,j;
                    i=m#(nx+1);
                    j=m-i*(nx+1);
                    v=(u*(j+1/2)/n, u*(i+1/2)/n);
                    if(inside(g[k], shift(v)*gb)==1){ 
                        count[i*(nx+1)+j]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int N=0;

        for(int m=0;m<count.length;++m){
            if(count[m]>0){
                int i,j;
                i=m#(nx+1);
                j=m-i*(nx+1);
                v=(u*j/n, u*i/n);
                draw(box(v,v+(u/n, u/n)),gray(0.3)+0.3bp);
                ++N;
            }
        }  
        label("$F$", (2,4));
        label("$N="+string(N)+"$",(gw,0),plain.NW);
    }

\end{asydef}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%
\begin{document}
    %
    \begin{figure}
        \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{asy}
            boxcount(g,3);
            \end{asy}
            %
            \caption{Step=3}
            \label{fig:1a}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{asy}
            boxcount(g,4);
            \end{asy}
            %
            \caption{Step=4}
            \label{fig:1b}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{asy}
            boxcount(g,5);
            \end{asy}
            %
            \caption{Step=5}
            \label{fig:1c}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \caption{Box-Counting}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
    %
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{asy}
        size(8cm);
        boxcount(g,6);
        \end{asy}
        \caption{Step=6}
        \label{fig:2}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
%
% Process:
%
% pdflatex boxcount.tex
% asy boxcount-*.asy
% pdflatex boxcount.tex
```

Comment: Asymptote has a boolean `inside(curve,point)` function, and arrays ?! That's cheating ! ;) Good work, thanks for the nice example !

Comment: @marsupilam:
Even better! It has `int inside(curve,curve)` as you can see in the code above.

Comment: While it's nice to count boxes, I guess OP would be glad if you could actually compute upper bounds for the **box dimension** of the domain : `dim(F) = - log(N_boxes)/log(box_side)`, as explained in the PDF lectures above.

Comment: @marsupilam: And the answer is `2`. 
(Or should I say `42`?).

Comment: Yeah it should be close to 2... The more boxes, the closer !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `metapost` solution that tests whether random points in grid squares are inside the given shape (and not inside a hole, if any).  Using fewer test points increases speed, but if only a small portion of a square lies inside the outline, then it may be missed (as you will see below if you look for them).
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\begin{mplibcode}
%https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103jackowski.pdf
vardef mock_arclength(expr p) =
  length((postcontrol 0 of p)-(point 0 of p)) +
  length((precontrol 1 of p)-(postcontrol 0 of p)) +
  length((point 1 of p)-(precontrol 1 of p))
enddef;
vardef windingangle(expr p,q) =
  save a,b,v;
  a=length(p-point 0 of q); b=length(p-point 1 of q);
    v:=mock_arclength(q);
    if (v>=a) and (v>=b):
      windingangle(p, subpath (0,1/2) of q)+windingangle(p, subpath (1/2,1) of q)
    else:
      v:=angle((point 1 of q)-p)-angle((point 0 of q)-p);
      if v>180: v:=v-360; fi
      if v<-180: v:=v+360; fi
      v
  fi
enddef;
vardef windingnumber (expr p,q) =
    save a; a:=0;
    for t:=1 upto length(q):
        a:=a+windingangle(p, subpath(t-1,t) of q);
    endfor
    a/360
enddef;

def boxes(suffix p)(expr m,t)= % p=path, m=mesh size, t=tries
    save sq_,maxh_,maxv_,tst_,cnt_,n_,k_;
    picture sq_; pair tst_;
    n_:=0;
    sq_:=image(draw unitsquare scaled m withpen pencircle scaled .5bp;);
    maxh_:=floor((xpart lrcorner p[0]-xpart llcorner p[0])/m);
    maxv_:=floor((ypart ulcorner p[0]-ypart llcorner p[0])/m);
    forever: draw p[n_]; exitif not (known p[incr n_]); endfor;
    for i=0 upto maxh_:
        for j=0 upto maxv_:
            cnt_:=0;
            forever:
                exitif (incr cnt_)>t; % too many tries
                tst_:=(llcorner p[0])+m*((i,j)+(uniformdeviate(1),uniformdeviate(1))); % rand point in grid square
                if (abs(windingnumber(tst_,p[0]))>eps): % inside shape?
                    if n_-1>=1: % any holes?
                        k_:=1;
                        % if not in a hole
                        if not (forever: (abs(windingnumber(tst_,p[k_]))>eps) exitif (not known p[incr k_]); or endfor):
                            draw sq_ shifted ((llcorner p[0])+m*(i,j));
                            exitif true;
                        fi
                    else:
                            draw sq_ shifted ((llcorner p[0])+m*(i,j));
                            exitif true;
                    fi
                fi
            endfor;
        endfor;
    endfor;
enddef;

beginfig(0);
    path p[];
    u:=40bp;
    % p[0] is outer shape
    p[0]:=(.9u,2.9u)..(2.9u,.5u)..(4.9u,.u)..(5u,-2.9u)..(-u,-2.9u)..(.1u,.9u)..cycle;
    % p[i], i>0 are holes.
    p[1]:=p[0] rotated 30 scaled .3 shifted (u,-u);
    p[2]:=fullcircle scaled u shifted (u,.75u);
    % first arg = array of paths, second arg = mesh size, 
    % third arg = max number of test points pre square.
    boxes(p,5bp,20);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```